# Multiply a grouped data frame by a matrix dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

## My problem:

I have two data frames, one for industries and one for occupations. They are nested by state, and show employment.

I also have a concordance matrix, which shows the weights of each of the occupations in each industry.

I would like to create a new employment number in the Occupation data frame, using the Industry employments and the concordance matrix.

I have made dummy version of my problem - which I think is clear:

## Update

I have solved the issue, but I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution? In reality my dimensions are 7 States * 200 industries * 350 Occupations it becomes rather data hungry

```
# create industry data frame

set.seed(12345)

ind_df <- data.frame(State = c(rep("a", len =6),rep("b", len =6),rep("c", len =6)),
                 industry = rep(c("Ind1","Ind2","Ind3","Ind4","Ind5","Ind6"), len = 18),
                 emp = rnorm(18,20,2))


# create occupation data frame

Occ_df <- data.frame(State = c(rep("a", len = 5), rep("b", len = 5), rep("c", len =5)),
                     occupation = rep(c("Occ1","Occ2","Occ3","Occ4","Occ5"), len = 15),
                     emp = rnorm(15,10,1))

# create concordance matrix
                     
Ind_Occ_Conc <- matrix(rnorm(6*5,1,0.5),6,5) %>% as.data.frame()

# name cols in the concordance matrix 

colnames(Ind_Occ_Conc) <- unique(Occ_df$occupation)
rownames(Ind_Occ_Conc) <- unique(ind_df$industry)

  

# solution 

Ind_combined <- cbind(Ind_Occ_Conc, ind_df)

Ind_combined <- Ind_combined %>%
  group_by(State) %>% 
  mutate(Occ1 = emp*Occ1,
         Occ2 = emp*Occ2,
         Occ3 = emp*Occ3,
         Occ4 = emp*Occ4,
         Occ5 = emp*Occ5
         )

Ind_combined <- Ind_combined %>% 
  gather(key = "occupation",
         value = "emp2",
         -State,
         -industry,
         -emp
         )

Ind_combined <- Ind_combined %>%
  group_by(State, occupation) %>%
  summarise(emp2 = sum(emp2))


Occ_df <- left_join(Occ_df,Ind_combined)
```

My solution seems pretty inefficient, is there a better / faster way to do this?

Also - I am not quite sure how to get to this - but the expected outcome would be another column added to the Occ_df called emp2, this would be derived from Ind_df emp column and the Ind_Occ_Conc. I have tried to step this out for Occupation 1, essentially the Ind_Occ_Conc contains weights and the result is a weighted average.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible with `set.seed` for `rnorm`, then also please show the expected output based on that input data

Comment: What is the relation/equation between `Ind_df$emp`, `Ind_Occ_Conc` values? You need to edit your question to provide the expected output.

Comment: Thanks both, both good comments. I have tried to make this clearer in the above, stepping through the what I expect the calculation to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want to do with the sum(Ind$emp*Occ1_coeff) line but maybe that's what your looking for :

```
# Instead of doing the computation only for state a, get expected outcomes for all states (with dplyr):
Ind <- ind_df %>% group_by(State) %>%
        summarize(rez = sum(emp))

# Then do some computations on Ind, which is a N element vector (one for each state)
# ...

# And finally, join Ind and Occ_df using merge
Occ_df <- merge(x = Occ_df, y = Ind, by = "State", all = TRUE)
```

Final output would then have Ind values in a new column: one value for all a, one value for b and one value for c.

Hope it will help ;)